# Unable to pull Docker images from private registry using Rancher

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rancher

I am new to Docker, Rancher and Kubernetes. I am using RancherOS and have installed Rancher server on it. When i try to connect a node to Rancher server, it connects fine but when Kubernetes tries to start services, most of the services fail with errors similar to the following:

```
Error (Image [index.docker.io/rancher/net:v0.11.5] failed to pull: Pulling repository docker.io/rancher/net)
```

Another similar message for a different component:
[image]

Docker version on Rancher server: `17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e`
Docker version on Rancher agent: `1.12.6, build 78d1802`

I created private registry which points to Artifactory. In the Kubernetes template, i specified the registry and that’s the only change i did in the template.

If i manually run the following commands, it works:

```
docker login docker.artifactory.abc.net -u svc-ranch-art_d
docker pull docker.artifactory.abc.net/rancher/net:v0.11.5
```

I can see in the Artifactory that the above version (0.11.5) gets cached. I am not sure that when Rancher tries starting services, why it goes to `docker.io`. Struggling since yesterday but couldn’t find anything.

Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Did you create the kubernetes secret? based on this step https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Comment: I see that `kubectl` utility is required for that. This executable is neither on the server nor on the agent. In case of Rancher, i think these will be created just after the step where i am currently stuck i.e., fetching images and starting services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i was able to resolve it. There is a global setting `registry.default` which had to be changed from its default to the private registry that i created. After that, the environment had to be recreated. I did change the `registry.default` value but did not re-create the environment. That was the issue.

[image]

Ref: http://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/installing-rancher/installing-server/no-internet-access/#using-a-private-registry

Comment: I am using Rancher Desktop 1.9.1. Where can I find global setting 'registry.default' ? and 'Admin -> Setting -> Advanced Settings'?